# How to disable Error (warning 66): unused open! in dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

As per https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1110, OCaml 4.08 and later raises a warning for unused module opens, even when they are opened with `open!`. This creates friction with the common practice of using `open! Foo` to establish that the following code is to be in the context of module `Foo` (whether or not any thing is used from inside of `Foo`). Moreover, since `dune` treats all warnings as fatal errors by default, this will cause dune builds in the default `dev` profile to fail with errors like

```
$ dune build
File "lib/mylib.ml", line 1, characters 0-10:
1 | open! Core
    ^^^^^^^^^^
Error (warning 66): unused open! Core.
```

How can I disable this warnings and the fatal error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [dune FAQ](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=warning%20flags#how-to-make-warnings-non-fatal) explains how to configure warnings so that they are "non-fatal" (letting the build proceed). However, this will still leave the warnings cluttering your build output. For developers using the `open! Foo` idiom to establish the context, this is annoying. The best solution is just **to selectively disable this warning** for the project:

- Create a `dune` file at the root of your project
- Add the following stanza

  ```
  (env
    (dev
      (flags (:standard -w -66))))
  ```

This stanza instructs `dune` to pass the `-w` flag with the `-66` argument to the OCaml compiler when building under the `dev` profile. `man ocamlc` explains how this flag works:

```
       -w warning-list
          Enable, disable, or mark as fatal the warnings specified by the argument warning-list.
          ...
          -num   Disable warning number num.
          ...
          The warning numbers are as follows.
          ...
          66   Unused open! statement.
```